# Invariantly convert ET DST/STD to UTC

Tags: c#, time, timezone

I have logs that had been written in ET DST timezome, parsed them and wrote to another log as UTC time (`date.ToUniversalTime().GetDateTimeFormats('G', CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)[0]`). Now (when standart time is enabled) I try to run unit tests that compare logs and I face in an issue that now times differ in a hour.

Is there any way to invariantly compare outputs without recreating logs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the pattern 'G' (General Date Time Pattern) that does not include any time zone information you should look at using the 'O' (Round-Trip Date Time Pattern) as that will preserve time zone information and structure the string in such a way that it is easy to sort on.

```
O: 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 2009-06-15T13:45:30.0900000
G: 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM -> 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM (en-US)
```